# analytic geometry ..... 2 problems

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

1st problem : find the equation of the straight line having slope $m$ passing through the point $(a, 0)$. What are the coordinates of the point of intersection of this line with the y-axis?
2nd problem : find an equation of the line passing through the point $(1, 5)$ with a negative slope and forms with the coordinates axis a triangle with area $10$ sq. units. Please I want answers with steps.

Thank you!

Comment: I believe almost identical questions have been asked here $n + 1$ times.

Comment: It is much easier to google: equation of a line.

Comment: So, what do you know about equations of lines? Hard to answer the questions in a helpful way without knowing that.

Comment: i have only 15 years old and i have try to solve them more than 5 times !

Comment: How about [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/Lines.aspx)?

Comment: yea i have tried by this roles but didn't make any difference ! :'(

Comment: ibrahim, please try to answer my question: what do you know about equations of lines?

Answer (score 1):

OP has gone to ground, but I find the second question shows some imagination, so I'll outline an answer. A line through $(1,5)$ has equation $$y-5=m(x-1)$$ for some $m$. When $x=0$, $y=5-m$; when $y=0$, $x=1-(5/m)$. The condition on the area of the triangle leads to $$(1/2)(5-m)(1-(5/m))=10$$ Clearing fractions, this is $$(5-m)(m-5)=20m$$ and from here it should be routine to solve.